# Cloudwatch Billing Alarm Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create a CloudWatch billing alarm example pic:

[Example of end-goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9TBJ.png)

it all seems fine, it's really strange I even get a HTTPStatusCode 200 when I run it but it does nothing, I've even waited 24 hours and checked but I can't see what I created... What am I missing? code below, please note I am using SSO and running against account id which I have not included in my code for privacy:

```
import boto3

sess = boto3.Session(profile_name='sso-account-here', region_name='us-east-1') #Billing region is US

cw = sess.client('cloudwatch')

    cw.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='Test 2',
    AlarmDescription='Test Alarm',
    ActionsEnabled=True,
    EvaluationPeriods=1,
    Threshold=2000,
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold',
    TreatMissingData='missing',
    Metrics=[
        {
            'Id': 'testalarm',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'AWS/Billing',
                    'MetricName': 'EstimatedCharges',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name':'Currency',
                            'Value':'USD'
                        },
                        {
                            'Name':'LinkedAccount',
                            'Value':'AWSACCOUNTIDHERE'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 21600,
                'Stat': 'Maximum',
                'Unit': 'Seconds'
            },
            'Label': 'EstimatedCharges > 1000 for 1 datapoints within 6 hours',
            'ReturnData': True,
        },
    ],
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was working after all, but you must include:

```
AlarmActions=['arn:forsnstopic'],
```

and create a valid SNS topic and subscription first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).